# Keep HTTP connection to speed up web page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm looking for how to keep connection  between browser and server after getting a resource (image).
So the problem is when browser looks for a image , it's take a lot of time to connect

[image]

The client request (HTTP/1.1):

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0‌​.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8 
Cache-Control:no-cache 
Connection:keep-alive
```

The server response (HTTP/1.1):

[image]

I think it's because 'close' value.

Comment: This is about server header response , it closes connection with browser , which reduces loading time

Comment: `Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive`

Comment: And this is server response :
`Accept-Ranges:none
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive, close`